# Does floor wipers help in getting rid of fat on hips?

Tags: fat, hip

Does floor wipers help in getting rid of fat on hips? Especially the fat that the guy is holding as shown in the figure? Or is there any specific exercise for the fat present at this region? My upper abs and lower abs are fine,But I am unable to lose fat present at this region.My height is 5.7 Feet and my weight is 131 pounds.I used to weigh 153.6 pounds but due to bit of control in my diet and daily exercise I got to 131 pounds.Not sure that it is fat or loose skin hanging after the fat loss.How to tone it up?

http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01528/fat_1528616c.jpg

Answer (score 4):

What you're referring to is "spot reduction", which is the idea that you can reduce fat in one particular area. This is a myth, and proven to be untrue in numerous studies ([2011 study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21804427) and [1983 study](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/.Ugnr2JLVCSo#.VCj5uPldV8E)).

> There was no significant effect of abdominal exercises on body weight,
>   body fat percentage, android fat percentage, android fat, abdominal
>   circumference, abdominal skinfold and suprailiac skinfold
>   measurements.

Muscle growth *is* localized, in that if you just exercised your arms only your arms would have increased muscle mass and strength.

But fat loss is across your body. **As such the most effective way at reducing body fat, wherever it is, is via proper nutrition.** If you can find it, I would recommend watching a movie called [Fed Up](https://www.google.com/search?q=fed%20up%20movie%20streaming&oq=fed%20up%20movie%20streaming&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6155j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=fed%20up%20movie) that recently came out. It does a decent job of explaining the fat storage mechanisms going on in your body, and the largest culprit to obesity (refined sugars in nearly every aspect of a "modern" diet).

Comment: Body fat works on the LIFO concept. Last In, First Out. So if you gain fat in your face, then stomach, then hips, it will come off in the order of hips, stomach, face.